# Admin section in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the correct Way to structure an admin section in an Rails application?
I'm not talking about Auth, but where to put the admin controllers, routing etc.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750032/should-frontend-and-backend-be-handled-by-different-controllers

Answer (score 5):

Namespaces.

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :projects
  resources :users
  # ...
end
```

Generate controllers with `rails generate controller admin/projects` etc.

(In Rails 2, it's `map.namespace :admin do ... end` and `./script/generate controller admin/projects`.)

Answer (score 0):

I used the [Typus plugin](http://github.com/fesplugas/typus) a while ago. It's fine for little projects, but for larger apps it can get messy. Also, when your db schema changes it doesn't adapt. I think it's a Rails deficience compared wth Django.